# How to do an external redirect in Flask framework

Tags: redirect, flask

I want to do an external redirect in Flask so that, when the `redirect()` function is used and the page is being redirected, the url in the browser should change. I am aware that the browser has to send a second request to the server.

I have built a route so that when I request for `localhost/profile/342/` or `localhost/profile/342/wrong-username/`, I want the server to serve the URL `localhost/profile/342/right-username/` with the URL changed in the browser. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
@appHandler.route('/profile/<int:userid>/', defaults = {'username' : None})
@appHandler.route('/profile/<int:userid>/<username>/')
def profile(userid, username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id = userid).first()
    if username != user.username:
        redirect(url_for('profile', userid = userid, username = user.username), code = 307)                                                                                                       
    return render_template('profile/profile.html', user = user)
```

I tried giving `code = 301` (though I was not even sure if it would work) as an argument for the `redirect()` function but it didn't work (the URL remained the same, but the page was served).

Any one has any suggestion?

Comment: Define *did not work* here. You are certainly using the right methodology, and in this case you should leave the HTTP code to the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *return* the response object produced by `redirect()`:

```
if username != user.username:
    return redirect(url_for('profile', userid=userid, username=user.username),
                    code=301)
```

I picked `code=301` here; Stack Overflow uses that status code for username redirects as well. You want browsers to use the 'current' username URL directly, not keep re-using the incorrect username.

Comment: Can you please explain the last sentence of your answer a bit more?

Comment: @kevin: Browsers can cache URLs, based on the response received from a server. A 307 response says 'Please go look here instead, but for your next request, it is fine if you use this URL again', so a cache or browser will keep re-requesting the incorrect URL with the username not matching. A 301 instead tells them: 'Sorry, this was the wrong URL, you really wanted to use the other one I redirected you to' and a browser or cache will in future go *straight* to the corrected URL instead of bothering your server.

Comment: That was clear now. So, now I see the default response code for a redirect is 302. Thanks!